# Best way to check if condition or exception is thrown

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

Right now I have a function that excepts a string and is supposed to return none if the user either:

- doesn't pass in a string **OR**
- a specific exception is thrown when performing an operation on the argument

Here is how I am doing this:

```
def fnctn(num_str):
    if not isinstance(num_str, str):
        return None
    try:
        num = phonenumbers.parse(num_str, 'US')
    except phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException:
        return None
    ...
```

I am just wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this. Like if I could check if the argument that was passed in was a string and check to see if the operation throws an exception or not on the same line?

Comment: What happens when you pass a non-string object to `phonenumbers.parse()`? What exceptions will it throw in that case? Perhaps it'll throw `phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException` still, or throw a `TypeError`  or `ValueError`, which you could catch in the same `except` line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the most reasonable way to do this in Python, I think. The downside of trying operations and then catching exceptions on objects which don't have well-defined behaviors is that they could be modified by the function you call. Checking whether it's a known type, i.e. `str`, as you do here, and if it is, then trying the operation keeps the kinds of weird behaviors to a minimum while still returning a valid result or an error (`None` in this case).